# How to use a Tab-Delimited UTF-16le file as source in a Microsoft Azure data Factory dataflow

Tags: azure, apache-spark-dataset, azure-data-factory

I am working for a customer in the medical business (so excuse the many redactions in the screenshots). I am pretty new here so excuse any mistakes I might make please.

We are trying to fill a SQL database table with data coming from 2 different sources (CSV files). Both are delivered on a BLOB storage where we have read access.

The first flow I build to do this with azure data factory works perfectly so I just thought to clone that flow and point it to the second source. However the CSV files from the second source are TAB delimited and UTF-16le encoded. Luckily you can set these parameters when you create a dataset:
[Dataset Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFNH4.png)
When I verify the dataset by using the "Preview Data" option, I see a nice list with data coming from the CSV file:[Output from preview data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWS3U.png) So it appears to work fine !

Now I create a new dataflow and in the source I use the newly created Data source. All settings I left at default. [data flow settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e18aj.png)

Now when I open Data Preview and click refresh I get garbage and NULL outputs instead of the nice data I received when testing the data source. [output from source block in dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfmTx.png) In my first dataflow i created this does produce the expected data from the csv file but somehow the data is now scrambled ?

Could someone please help me with what I am missing or doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to repro and here you could see if you have the Dataset settings,

Encoding as `UTF-8` instead of `UTF-16` then you will ne able to preview the data.

[image]

Data Preview inside the Dataflow:

[image]

And if even I try to have the `UTF-16LE` enabled for the encoding having such issues:

[image]

Hence, for now you could change the `Encoding` and use the pipeline.

Comment: Hi, so sorry for the delay in my response. Life got in the way of work.  The problem is that I can use UTF-8 or UTF16LE in the Dataset settings and the preview data in the dataset settings show my data correctly (i even tried about 20 other encodings as well).  However, when i use this dataset in as source in my dataflow it shows garbage

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug where the Dataflow (stupidly) reads the row ends \r\n as single bytes still when the file is UTF-16LE.  In other words its looking for 0D 0A when in fact the file has 0D 00 0A 00 and the extra bytes cause havoc in a load.

You can detect UTF16-LE by reading the file as lines of UTF8 and checking the first two bytes for the "Byte Order Mark" (see wikipedia) or alternatively you may know already that's what type it is.

To fix - put two data sets on the file, one UTF16LE and one UTF8 and use an ADF copy from the 16 bit dataset to the 8 bit dataset before you do anything else.  This will down-convert the file.